# How to open a port on linux (Debian jessie)

Tags: linux, port, iptables, nmap

I have a process that I'm running on my local machine which is listening on TCP port 9000. I would like to consume on another computer of my network. Here is my configuration:

**I would like to see it when I run `nmap 10.18.12.12`** but I don't know how.

```
nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-08-20 13:49 ART
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00037s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 987 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
443/tcp  open  https
631/tcp  open  ipp
3306/tcp open  mysql
5432/tcp open  postgresql
8000/tcp open  http-alt
**9000/tcp open  cslistener**
9001/tcp open  tor-orport
9999/tcp open  abyss
```

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-08-20 13:45 ART
Nmap scan report for 10.18.12.12
Host is up (0.00073s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

Comment: You want to open a port? You might want to read up on [iptables](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianFirewall), but be careful if your other system is a server you can easily lock yourself out by accident.

Comment: It's a node server. i would like to test it over my network, it runs on locally. 
 I've run: 
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
iptables-save

But i still have the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

The service is bound to 127.0.0.1. You can see this without using Nmap; use netstat instead: `netstat -tln` will show all listening TCP ports. You should see something like this:

```
$ netstat -tln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

In this example, the service on port 21 (FTP) is listening on the special address `0.0.0.0` which means "any available address," but the service on port 9000 is bound to `127.0.0.1`, which is a special address ("localhost" or "loopback") not accessible from the network.

Most services will have a way to specify which addresses or interfaces to listen on. Read the manual for the service you are interested in to determine how to change this.